# Copying formula to count the number of rows which have a value to another column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is an excel table which looks like,

```
x, 1,  , 3
y,  , 1, 2
z, 2,  , 3
```

the desired output is,

```
x    , 1,  , 3
y    ,  , 1, 2
z    , 2,  , 3

count, 2, 1, 3
```

I apply the formula to one column, but how to apply this to all the columns?

Comment: What is your current formula?

Comment: =COUNT(AK4:AK238), for column AK

Comment: Please add this to your question - and propably a screenshot - otherwise it's hard to understand what is in AK ..

Comment: How if `0` not a value? The `count` function only ignores a cell if is has *non-numeric* value.

Comment: You could use a table (insert > table) and then use the result row for your formula and the according columns

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, I have changed the question, zero is not there in the table

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this is to drag the cells from the right bottom corner and it will automatically apply the formula to the next cells